# Buttons append to div

Tags: javascript

i have  to make a "To do list " using only js .I already make a div with an input , an textarea and a date input  how can i  add "edit" and "save" button in my div.I have no clue how to add them using my button function .Any ideea how can i add them  into my div ? Here is my javascript code .

JS

```js
function ToDo() {
    this.divleft= new divleft()
    this.saveButton = new Button('Save')
    this.editButton = new Button('Edit')

   
    this.initialize = function () {
        this.divleft.render();
        this.saveButton.render();
        this.editButton.render();


    }
}
function divleft() {
  
    this.render = function () {
        
        this.div = document.createElement('div');
        this.div.setAttribute('id', 'divleft');
        this.label = document.createElement('label');
        this.input = document.createElement("input");
        this.input.setAttribute("type", "text");
        this.textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        this.labelt = document.createElement('label');
        this.labeld=document.createElement('label');
        this.inputd=document.createElement('input');
        this.inputd.setAttribute('type', 'date');
        this.br1=document.createElement('br');
        this.br2=document.createElement('br');
        this.br3=document.createElement('br');
        this.br4=document.createElement('br');

        document.body.appendChild(this.div);
        this.div.appendChild(this.label).appendChild(this.input);
        this.div.appendChild(this.br1);
        this.div.appendChild(this.br2);
        this.div.appendChild(this.labelt).appendChild(this.textarea);
        this.div.appendChild(this.br3);
        this.div.appendChild(this.br4);
        this.div.appendChild(this.labeld).appendChild(this.inputd);
        
        
    }
    
}

function Button(text) {
    this.text = text;

    this.render = function () {
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerText = text;
        document.body.appendChild(button);
    }
}

function Break() {
    this.render = function () {
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        document.body.appendChild(br);
    }
}
new ToDo().initialize();
```

```css
#divleft{
    width: 190px;
    height:150px;
    Border: 1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to add them when you click on save?

Comment: How is this question different to your [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197758/how-can-i-append-child) - other than that you're appending buttons now instead of a textarea?

Comment: for now i want to  add them in my left div .And after i hit save to create another div, but this is  another story . All i want is to appendchild those 2 buttons in my "#divleft".@Andreas i manage somehow to add them together . but i want to add them from another function"function button"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass to your render function the div where you want to render to. For example you can pass the div that you created and render there.

```js
function ToDo() {
    this.divleft= new divleft()
    this.saveButton = new Button('Save')
    this.editButton = new Button('Edit')

   
    this.initialize = function () {
        this.divleft.render();
        this.saveButton.render(this.divleft);
        this.editButton.render(this.divleft);


    }
}
function divleft() {
  
    this.render = function () {
        
        this.div = document.createElement('div');
        this.div.setAttribute('id', 'divleft');
        this.label = document.createElement('label');
        this.input = document.createElement("input");
        this.input.setAttribute("type", "text");
        this.textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        this.labelt = document.createElement('label');
        this.labeld=document.createElement('label');
        this.inputd=document.createElement('input');
        this.inputd.setAttribute('type', 'date');
        this.br1=document.createElement('br');
        this.br2=document.createElement('br');
        this.br3=document.createElement('br');
        this.br4=document.createElement('br');

        document.body.appendChild(this.div);
        this.div.appendChild(this.label).appendChild(this.input);
        this.div.appendChild(this.br1);
        this.div.appendChild(this.br2);
        this.div.appendChild(this.labelt).appendChild(this.textarea);
        this.div.appendChild(this.br3);
        this.div.appendChild(this.br4);
        this.div.appendChild(this.labeld).appendChild(this.inputd);
        
        
    }
    
}

function Button(text) {
    this.text = text;

    this.render = function (div) {
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerText = text;
        debugger;
        div.div.appendChild(button);
    }
}

function Break() {
    this.render = function () {
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        document.body.appendChild(br);
    }
}
new ToDo().initialize();
```

```css
#divleft{
    width: 190px;
    height:150px;
    Border: 1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: This is working . I will mark corect answer in few minute . Ty